# Delete records from local store only in ember

Tags: ember.js, delete-record

How do I delete records from the local store only in Ember?
My store has a a record type of vdpmodel with 3 records in it, which I have created in the local store. I want to delete a specific record in vdpmodel, without ember requesting any data from the server.

I tried the tutorial in the Ember website, using find(..).then function(delete), but that makes a request to the server, which I don't want it to do.

In theory, I want something like the following:

this.store.all('vdpmodel',{type:"abc"}).then(function(data){data.deleteRecord();});

But it errors with 'the function is undefined'

Any ideas on how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

This is also a bit different from the unloadRecord question as I can't use this the find function to unload the record as the records exist only locally.

Comment: var records = this.store.filterBy('vdpmodel', 'type', 'abc');
records.forEach(function(record){
  record.deleteRecord();
});

You can try above code.

Comment: Hi Swati, it says undefined is not a function on  var records=this.store.filterBy('vdpmodel','type','abc');.

Comment: Instead of filterBy, can you please try with filter? just replace filterBy with filter... http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

Comment: Hi Swathi, instead of deleting I tried printing out if there's any content in records using the following code, but it returned with 0.    var records=this.store.filter('vdpmodel',function(record){
                record.get("type")=="abc";
            });            
            console.log(records.get("length")); My store contents are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtp6zlap66noaes/ember%20datastore.png?dl=0  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are developing a demo app without any actual api? and you are using localStorage adapter? refer https://github.com/swatijadhav/ember_todo_app

Comment: I have an actual api. But for the particular function I am trying to do, I create some local models in order to create the record that has to be pushed up to the api.

Comment: ok it looks like as you are getting count 0 then instead of suing filter directly you need to use promise function there.. as records are not available in your data-store and hence filter returns no records. Try using promise at filter, It should return you the filtered records.

Comment: Hi Swati, thanks for your help. I managed to solve this by first doing a store.all and then  doing a filterby based on the result.var records = this.store.all('vdpmodel'); 
            var filteredRecords=records.filterBy("type","abc");
            filteredRecords.forEach(function(data){
                data.deleteRecord();
            });

Comment: great.. using store.all will first check your data-store, if it has records then it will return those else it will query to your api... and hence it solved your issue here.. Glad to know that you got the answer.. :)