# Delete record whose model exists only locally Ember

Tags: ember.js, delete-record

I have this record I have created whose model only exists locally (not in the api). 
The model is as follows:

```
TM.Vdpmodel=DS.Model.extend({
type:DS.attr(),
description:DS.attr(),
vds:DS.attr(),    
});
```

I use this model to create an array of objects (vdps) in the JSON. See below.

```
{"vdps":[{"type":"ssdfdfg","description":"fhfgh","vds":[{"type":"fghgh","example":"jghhgj"},{"type":"gjghj","example":"ghjghj"},{"type":"ghjghj","example":"ghjghj"}]}],"asset_usage":[]}
```

I create them using

```
TM.obj.vdp.pushObject(this.store.createRecord('vdpmodel',{
            type:this.get("vdp11"),
            description:this.get("vdp12"),
            vds:TM.vdobj.vd.objectsAt([this.get("vdcount"),this.get("vdcount")+1,this.get("vdcount")+2])   
}));
```

This record is only stored locally. Now I want to delete a record from this store which has a whose type value is "abc". How do I do this? Keeping in mind, the record only exists locally at the moment.

I've tried the following:

```
var records=this.store.filter('vdpmodel',function(data){
  return data.get('type')==="abc";
});  
records.forEach(function(record){
  record.deleteRecord();
});
```

But records is never populated. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using a filterby on the results of a store.all

```
var records = this.store.all('vdpmodel'); 
var filteredRecords=records.filterBy("type","abc");
filteredRecords.forEach(function(data){
     data.deleteRecord();
});
```

Comment: I think you should removeObject because the record exists locally only and doesn't need to sync with backend.  deleteRecord will result in call to server to `commit` the changes, since it's local so call is not required.

Comment: You should be using unloadRecord as was mentioned in your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648200/delete-records-from-local-store-only-in-ember

Comment: I've tried it with both uloadRecord & deleteRecord, both seems to be doing the same thing.